# How do I Return 0 From a MySQL db When the Term in the Where Clause is Not in the database?

Tags: mysql, select, null

How do I get my mysql database to return 0 if the neighborhood in the WHERE clause doesn't exist? So in the example below, Old Town is not in the database. I'd like the database to return 0 incidents instead of an empty result.

```
SELECT incidents, 
       neighborhoods 
 FROM `myTable` 
WHERE neighborhoods ='Old Town'
```

I also tried

```
SELECT IFNULL(incidents,0), 
       IFNULL(neighborhoods,0) 
  FROM `myTable` 
 WHERE neighborhoods ='Old Town'
```

Any suggestions would be really appreciated.

Comment: Generally people are perfectly content getting back an empty result set when there is no matching record in the database. Why is this a problem for you? What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: Hi Asaph,

Thank you for the message. I've simplified my example a bit. Basically, I am selecting from several tables, making an average of the incidents and then repeating this process with other tables, and then returning the entire result to my Flex app.

So my code works, except when the neighborhood doesn't exist in the table. 

I've also got a problem when calculating the average

(SELECT ROUND((SUM( incidents )/4),1) AS avg_annual_incidents...

where I can have 0/4

I'm limited in the number of characters I'm permitted in this message. I'll post another message.

Thanks

-Laxmidi

Comment: Hi Asaph,

My code looks more like the following:

$query = "(SELECT ROUND((SUM( incidents )/4.087),1) AS avg_annual_incidents, neighborhoods,  'adw' as offense 
FROM (
SELECT * 
FROM `adw_2009_incident_location` 
UNION ALL SELECT * 
FROM `adw_2008_incident_location`
UNION ALL SELECT * 
FROM `adw_2007_incident_location`
UNION ALL SELECT * 
FROM `adw_2006_incident_location`
UNION ALL SELECT * 
FROM adw_jan1_feb1_2010_incident_location
) AS combo WHERE neighborhoods = '$neighborhood_id'
GROUP BY neighborhoods )  
UNION ALL
(it continues in the same pattern with different tables 6 more times).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My take on your issue is to construct a derived table of the `neighborhoods` values you hope to find, and `LEFT JOIN` to the actual table:

```
   SELECT x.neighborhoods,
          COALESCE(mt.incidents, 0) AS incidents
     FROM (SELECT 'Old Town' AS neighborhoods
             FROM DUAL
           UNION ALL
           SELECT 'New Town'
             FROM DUAL) x
LEFT JOIN MYTABLE mt ON mt.neighborhoods = x.neighborhoods
```

Comment: OMG Ponies, 
I followed your advice. I have a neighborhoods table and I used it to make a LEFT JOIN. Thank you.

All the best.
-Laxmidi

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(incidents), 0), 'Old Town'
FROM `myTable`
WHERE neighborhoods = 'Old Town'
```

Comment: What if there are multiple rows matching the condition in the `WHERE` clause? In that case, it seems like the OP wants all the rows returned rather than aggregated.

Comment: Mark, 

Thank you for your comment.
-Laxmidi

Answer (score 0):

You can add `COUNT(*)` into the select part, which gives you the amount of rows in the result set. As long you want to read only one row it gives you either *0* or *1*.

```
SELECT COUNT(*), Foo, Bar FROM Bla WHERE false;
+----------+-----+-----+
| COUNT(*) | Foo | Bar |
+----------+-----+-----+
|        0 | NULL | NULL |
+----------+-----+-----+

SELECT COUNT(*), Foo, Bar FROM Bla WHERE Bar = 0;
+----------+------------+-----+
| COUNT(*) | Foo        | Bar |
+----------+------------+-----+
|        1 | 2147483647 |   0 |
+----------+------------+-----+
```

But if you would get more than one row it may fail as you get only one row from the result set.

```
SELECT COUNT(*), Foo, Bar FROM Bla WHERE Bar >= 0;
+----------+-----+-----+
| COUNT(*) | Foo | Bar |
+----------+-----+-----+
|        7 |   3 |   6 |
+----------+-----+-----+
```

(And don't forget to use an alias for the `COUNT(*)` column)

Comment: Hi Progman,

Thank you for the idea. I can use an if statement with

SELECT COUNT( * ) AS myCount
FROM `myTable` 
WHERE neighborhoods = 'Old Town' as a condition in my function. This would return 0, which is what I want. 

But, how would I set neighborhood's value as "Old Town" and the incident's value as 0? I don't think that I want to use SET and UPDATE. Any suggestions?

Thank you!
-Laxmidi

Answer (score 0):

If you need to return 0 from the DB i suggest using a function.

Otherwise, you could check existence from code by using a COUNT() query before executing the actual query.

Comment: mcabral,
Thank you for the suggestion.
-Laxmidi